# Google Cloud Endpoints Auth Exception from Android App

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

In my Android application I have problem with authenticated calls to a Google AppEngine app using Google Cloud Endpoints.

Here is my endpoint method:

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "compute", clientIds = { Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        Ids.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }, 
        audiences = { Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID }, 
        scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" })
public Response compute(Request req, User user) {
    if (user == null) {
        return new Response("HELLO, " + req.getMessage());
    } else {
        return new Response("HELLO, " + user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Initialize the GoogleAccountCredential:

```
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
            "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);       
    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(mAndroidUtils.getAccountName(this));
```

Make async call to my endpoint:

```
    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Myendpoint.Builder builder = new Myendpoint.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new JacksonFactory(), mCredential);
            Myendpoint anEndpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                    builder).build();

            Request r = new Request();
            r.setMessage("World!");
            return anEndpoint.compute(r).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Respone = new Respone ();
            r.setValue("EXCEPTION");
            return r;
        }
    }
```

I have deployed my project to App engine.
In Api explorer everything works excellent, but when I run it on my android device I got exception: GoogleAuthException: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown.

I have read almost everything about App engine and Google Cloud Endpoints in Stackoverflow. The most frequent mistakes is using ANDROID_CLIENT_ID instead of WEB_CLIENT_ID or specifying wrong SHA1 fingerprint, during creation ANDROID_CLIENT_ID. I have checked all ids many times, but it doesn't work. Please, help.